# DHCPv6 Options for Network Time Server

Tags: networking, dhcp, ntp

While for DHCPv4 there appears to be exactly one option to specify (S)NTP servers, namely 42, DHCPv6 seems to offer two separate ones:

- `OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS` (31) uses the same configuration format as DHCPv4 where a list of IP addresses are specified
- `OPTION_NTP_SERVER` (56) allows 3 different suboptions to be specified, either an IP address, a Multicast IP address or a Fully Qualified Domain Name

According to [RFC 5908](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5908) where `OPTION_NTP_SERVER` is specified:

> This option serves as a container for server location information
> related to one NTP server or Simple Network Time Protocol (SNTP)
> server.
> This option can appear multiple times in a DHCPv6    message.  Each
> instance of this option is to be considered by the NTP    client or
> SNTP client as a server to include in its configuration.

This means that with `OPTION_NTP_SERVER` even more information about the network time server can be provided compared to `OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS`. So why does the `OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS` exist alongside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking RFC 5908 again it is stated in [section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5908.html#section-7) that RFC 4075 is deprecated (`OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS`) and RFC 5908 (`OPTION_NTP_SERVER`) shall be used instead.

As for the reasons that led to the decision the following information is provided:

> [...] this approach [RFC 4075] is not suitable for    all NTP deployments.  It is not an extensible mechanism and    **introduces some semantic confusion**
> through the use of the "SNTP"    acronym.  Additionally, the approach
> of **only offering IPv6 addresses    to specify server location does not
> meet NTP requirements** that make    use of an FQDN (Fully-Qualified
> Domain Name) as well.

To sum it up, the additional suboptions allow for more different ways of specifying the S(NTP) server location and the old `OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS` led to confusion whether it can also be used for NTP.

The deprecation leads to a discrepancy in the way NTP servers need to be specified for DHCPv4 and DHCPv6. While DHCPv6 introduced the new suboption based approach, DHCPv4 still only allows the specification of a list of IP addresses similar to RFC 4075 (`OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS`).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community.

As per [RFC4330 (Simple Network Time Protocol (SNTP) Version 4 for IPv4, IPv6 and OSI)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc4330/) page 1

> Simple Network Time Protocol Version 4 (SNTPv4) ... is a subset
> of the Network Time Protocol (NTP) ...

and

> ...can be used when the ultimate performance of a full NTP implementation
> based on RFC 1305 is neither needed nor justified.

This is a comparable situation to TFTP and FTP. Using simpler protocols simplifies setups, reduces overhead etc. Removing `OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS` from DHCPv6 would mean solutions using IPv6 would require full NTP implementations.

Comment: Thank you for your warm welcome and the fast response. If I understand [RFC 5908](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5908) correctly `OPTION_NTP_SERVER` can be used to specify both NTP and SNTP servers as they share the same message format ([RFC 4330, section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4330#section-4)). They mostly differ in the client implementation on how to correct time based on those messages. Furthermore, DHCPv4 only provides one option (42) to specify time servers. So why is the differentiation made for DHCPv6?

Comment: You's correct. Unfortunately I can't give better answer than this. In general "Why is this implemented this way?" can only be answered by the implementor. Maybe the answer can be found somewhere in the IETF NTP working group mail archives? :-)

Answer (score 0):

> This means that with OPTION_NTP_SERVER even more information about the network time server can be provided compared to OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS. So why does the OPTION_SNTP_SERVERS exist alongside it?

The SNTP_SERVERS option **[was added first](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4075).** It does not stop existing when newer options are added – at most, it is marked "deprecated", but implementations that used to support it will most likely continue to support it.

OPTION_NTP_SERVER only appeared [five years later](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5908), with the goal of extending the older SNTP-only option and a deprecation note for it:

> 7. RFC 4075 Deprecation
>
> "Simple Network Time Protocol (SNTP) Configuration Option for DHCPv6"
> [RFC4075] provides some degree of automatic time server configuration
> for IPv6, as it specifies how to transmit SNTP [RFC4330] server
> addresses through DHCPv6.  However, this approach is not suitable for
> all NTP deployments.  It is not an extensible mechanism and
> introduces some semantic confusion through the use of the "SNTP"
> acronym.  Additionally, the approach of only offering IPv6 addresses
> to specify server location does not meet NTP requirements that make
> use of an FQDN (Fully-Qualified Domain Name) as well.  For all the
> abovementioned reasons, this document makes [RFC4075] deprecated.